# Windows 8.1 phone emulator debug Error . Error code 0*80131500

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-emulator

I am using Windows 8.1 and Blend for Microsoft VS 2013 (Version 12.0.50... Update with RC ), when I run the project it shows the following error

: There was problem starting the emulator. Error code 0*80131500

I already enable Hyper-V from Windows Feature but still its not working